# Prove that if $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$ then $\zeta_p$ not constructible

Tags: galois-theory

> Prove that if $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, $p>5$ then $\zeta_p$ not constructible

How to do this? There is a theorem in my book that says that the regular $n$-gon is constructible iff $n=2^k\cdot n_0$ where $n_0$ is the product of distinct Fermat primes, but I don't know how to apply it here since we are talking about an infinitude of primes.

Comment: Take a Fermat prime modulo 8.

Comment: Surely you want to require $p>5$

Comment: @Dzoooks I only know the first four Fermat primes: 3,5,17,257

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz  What I mean is, take $2^{2^n}+1 \pmod{8}.$  You should be able to piece together the rest.

Comment: @Dzoooks I don't see it.. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz Check my answer.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime? An integer denoted  $p$ is usually a prime, but it is still "safer" to state it explicitly. Here it actually matters, as a regular $85=5\cdot17$-gon is constructible, and $85\equiv5\pmod8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $p > 5$ is constructible and $p \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$.  Since $p$ must be a Fermat prime, we have $p=2^{2^n}+1$ for some $n \geq 2$.  But $$8=2^3 \mid 2^{2^n} \implies p \equiv 1 \pmod{8},$$ a contradiction.

---

The same proof would show that if $q \equiv 3,5,7 \pmod{8}$ with $3, 5 \nmid q$, then $\zeta_q$ is not constructible.

Answer (score 2):

$\zeta_p$ has degree $\phi(p)=p-1 \equiv 4 \bmod 8$.

Now, $p-1 > 4$ because $p>5$. If $p-1$ were a power of $2$, then $p-1 \equiv 0 \bmod 8$.

Therefore, $p-1$ cannot be a power of $2$ and so $\zeta_p$ cannot be constructible.